# how to extract value from hidden filed with id and value in jmeter using regex

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

Hi I am working with JMeter. My application is developed on java. In one of the request i am getting response

`HTTP Request Parameter:=_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN`

HTTP Request
value="nznrkrogryJurbnP2nkEB2AFXdVdU.mk43XesvDZwFjTWEgWgx.VfqTzOlOfH01kzvkUF9S5RGXPs6TMhoApEn1rGdaBnFqjccd8sxXpupFoWX1aMIw.i60XH2nUB2wti5Sy5A=="

When I check the page source I found that it comes from one of the hidden html control.
It is

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN"
       id="_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN"              
       value="nznrkrogryJurbnP2nkEB2AFXdVdU.mk43XesvDZwFjTWEgWgx.VfqTzOlOfH01kzvkUF9S5RGXPs6TMhoApEn1rGdaBnFqjccd8sxXpupFoWX1aMIw.i60XH2nUB2wti5Sy5A==" />
```

So please help me how to extract value string from above xpath using regex.

Comment: You question is not clear. What is this response you are getting , try to show it more clearly, then you talk about xpath using regex, what do you mean ?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in above comment `regular expression` and `xpath query` are quite a different things and you'd better formulate your question more clearly.

In case you want to extract _CONFIRMATIONTOKEN value into variable and use it in the further requests(s) you can possibly use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) applied to the request sampler that returns mentioned response.

Your XPath query should return value you want to extract.
In this case it will look like:

```
//input[@type="hidden"][@name="_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN"]/@value
```

Extracted value will be stored in jmeter variable pointed in 'Reference Name' field of XPath Extractor (e.g. `${token}` in your case). So you can use extracted variable in the further requests using this variable.

**NOTE:** Since here XPath Extractor is used to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).